# Integrate Product of Modified Bessel Functions of First and Second Kind

Tags: integration, bessel-functions

I need the following integration to solve a much larger problem:

$$\int rI_0(kr)K_0(kr)dr$$

I've looked through the typical integration tables but haven't found this particular combination. Maybe I've somehow missed it? Seems like this would be well known.

I've tried integrating by parts but it doesn't seem to get anywhere:

$$\int I_0(kr)rK_0(kr)dr=\frac{1}{k}I_0(kr)K_1(kr)+\int I_1(kr)rK_1(kr)$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [integral representation](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E16)
\begin{equation}
I_{\mu}\left(x\right)K_{\nu}\left(x\right)=\int_{0}^{\infty}J_{\mu\pm\nu}\left(2x\sinh t\right)e^{(-\mu\pm\nu)t}\mathrm{d}t
\end{equation} 
we can express, by changing the order of integration
\begin{align}
\int r\,I_0(kr)\, K_0(kr)\,dr&=\frac 1 {k^2}\int x\,I_0(x)\, K_0(x)\,dx\\
&=\frac1{k^2}\int x\,dx\int_{0}^{\infty}J_0\left(2x\sinh t\right)\,dt\\
&=\frac1{k^2}\int_0^\infty\,dt\int_0^\infty xJ_0\left(2x\sinh t\right)\,dx
\end{align}
Now, the $x$ integration is simple:
\begin{equation}
\int r\,I_0(kr)\, K_0(kr)\,dr=\frac1{k^2}\int_0^\infty \frac{xJ_1\left(2x\sinh t\right)}{2\sinh t}\,dt
\end{equation} 
We use the [recurrence relation](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.6.E1) for the Bessel functions
\begin{equation}
2\frac{J_1(X)}{X}=J_0(X)+J_1(X)
\end{equation}
to write
\begin{equation}
\frac{J_1\left(2x\sinh t\right)}{2\sinh t}=\frac{1}{2x}\left(  J_0\left(2x\sinh t\right)+J_2\left(2x\sinh t\right)\right)
\end{equation} 
and by using twice the integral representation given above with the positive sign, $\mu=\nu=0$ and $\mu=\nu=1$:
\begin{align}
\int r\,I_0(kr)\, K_0(kr)\,dr&=\frac{x^2}{2k^2}\left[
\int_0^\infty J_0\left(2x\sinh t\right)\,dt+\int_0^\infty J_2\left(2x\sinh t\right)\,dt
\right]\\
&=\frac{x^2}{2k^2}\left[I_0(x)K_0(x)+I_1(x)K_1(x)\right]
\end{align}
Reintroducing the original variables:
$$
\int r\,I_0(kr)\, K_0(kr)\,dr=\frac{r^2}2\left[I_0(kr)K_0(kr)+I_1(kr)K_1(kr)\right]
$$
which can be checked by direct derivation. However I could not find the correspondance with the Meijer function proposed by @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: If, in your last formula, $x=kr$ we have a problem except for $k=1$. What I gave just comes from a CAS. Cheers :-)

Comment: Merci d'avoir noté l'erreur ! I think we both made a mistake in the simple substitution $x=kr$! There was a $k^{-2}$ factor, not $1/k$. I think the result is now correct.

Comment: Hi Paul ! How could we show that this is almost a straight line ? By the way, what are you doing ? Your profile is quite laconic. Cheers :-)

Comment: $I_0(x)K_0(x)=(2x)^{-1}+O(x^{-3})$. Both functions are very similar for $x>0.5$. I work in soft matter physics at ESPCI, you may know this institution.

Comment: Pierre-Gilles de Gennes was a very good friend of mine; we also worked together in Pau (he was visiting our lab almost every year).

Comment: I see... Adichats !

Comment: This is form of the result I expected based on section 2.1.7 of http://web.eah-jena.de/~rsh/Forschung/Stoer/besint.pdf. Not sure why it wasn't included there. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Coming from a CAS,
$$\int r\,I_0(kr)\, K_0(kr)\,dr=\frac{r^2}{4 \sqrt{\pi }}\,\, G_{1,3}^{2,1}\left(k r,\frac{1}{2}|
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{1}{2} \\
 0,0,-1
\end{array}
\right)$$ where appears Meijer G-function (it is very close to linearity).

Answer (score 0):

We can actually do this with a fairly simple manipulation of the differential equations satisfied by $u_a(x) = I_0(ax)$ and $v_a(x) = K_0(ax)$. These are both solutions to
$$ (xy')' = a^2 x y . $$
Hence
$$ (xu_a')'v_b - (xv_b')' v_a = (a^2-b^2) x u_a v_b , $$
and the left-hand side is
$$ xu_a'' v_b - x u_a v_b'' + u_a''v_b - u_a v_b'' = (x(u_a' v_b - u_a v_b'))' $$
Integrating thus gives
$$ \int x u_a(x) v_b(x) \, dx = \frac{x(u_a' v_b - u_a v_b')}{a^2-b^2}  $$
But we want $a=b=1$. Applying L'Hopital's rule to $a \to b$ gives
$$ \int x u_b(x) v_b(x) \, dx = \frac{x}{2b} \left. \partial_a (u_a' v_b - u_a v_b') \right|_{a=b} . $$
We calculate
$$ \begin{align}
u_a(x) &= I_0(ax) & v_a'(x) &= a I_0'(ax) \\
\left. \partial_a u_a(x) \right|_{a=b}  &= x I_0'(bx) & \left. \partial_a u_a'(x) \right|_{a=b} &= I_0'(bx) + b I_0''(bx) ,
\end{align} $$
so
$$ \int x I_0(bx)K_0(bx) \, dx = \frac{x}{2b} ( (I_0'(bx) + b I_0''(bx)) K_0(bx) - x I_0'(bx) K_0'(bx)) , $$
and of course $ I'_0(bx) = b I_1(bx) $, $K_0'(bx) = -K_1(bx)$ and $I_0'(bx) + b I_0''(x) = bx I_0(bx) $ using the differential equation, so
$$ \int x I_0(bx)K_0(bx) \, dx = \frac{x^2}{2} (I_0(bx)K_0(bx)+ I_1(bx) K_1(bx)) . $$
Of course the same will work with other combinations of Bessel functions of the same order.